# wordWrap="true" does not work in Flex Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

in Flex Datagrid, I need to support line wrap function in one column.
In theory I need to set wordWrap="true" and variableRowHeight="true". It works well.

But the problem is that if in the cloumn I set itemRenderer="lc.monitoring.logviewer.components.CustomColumnRenderer" properties, then the line wrap funciton does not take effect.  It seems that the line wrap function can not work with itemRenderer in the datagrid column.

Any one can help me about this.

Comment: What is `CustomColumnRenderer` - what does it inherit from? What control does it use to display text? Post the code if you have it

Comment: CustomColumnRenderer is a <mx:Label> and it used to display text with a underline. I can post the code later

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Label` - it is for displaying a single line of text.

> The `Label` control displays a single line of noneditable text. Use the `Text` control to create blocks of multiline noneditable text.

`mx.controls.Text` supports [multiline text and wordwrap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Text.html)

> If the control is not as wide as the text, the text will wordwrap. The text is always aligned top-left in the control.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to override measure and updateDisplaylist inside your itemrenderer.
Your item renderer does not know how to resize the height in order to allow showing info inside the dg

Comment: Your said make sense, but I do not know how to implement it. Could you give me some detail example about this?
Thanks

Comment: MEASURE     http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=ascomponents_advanced_148_13.html

Comment: updateDisplayList   http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=skinning_071_11.html

Comment: you need to compute the needed size for the control to be displayed.
I also recommend you to take a look at the flex DataGridItemRenderer class definition and mechanism. you can find it in package mx.controls.dataGridClasses   and explore the code there :)